# Enumeration inside a paragraph

Tags: numbering

For starters this question might have already been asked and answered, but as I do not know how to properly call what I want, I cannot find an answer.

So I was wondering how can you do enumeration inside paragraphs? the `\begin{enumerate}...\end{enumerate}` is nice, but it is not quite what I want. I want to insert same enumeration in my paragraphs without the enumeration part having its own newline (if that makes sense). So something like: "[...] Note that (1.) .... By (1.), we conclude that...".

Is there a way to do with LaTeX, or does everyone just insert the enumeration by hand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `enumitem` package with the `inline` option. Starred `enumerate` environments will look like what you are asking for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
This is an example paragraph meant to demonstrate
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
    \item how enumitem works
    \item with the inline option
    \item compared to the unstarred version
\end{enumerate}

This is an example paragraph meant to demonstrate
\begin{enumerate*}[label=(\arabic*)]
    \item how enumitem works
    \item with the inline option
    \item compared to the unstarred version
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: We posted the same answer a the same time. Yours has an additional typo, the package is enumitem not enumerate. :))

Comment: Thanks for catching that!

Comment: In addition to this (perfect) answer, I find the options `itemjoin` and `itemjoin*` pretty useful for inline enums. You can try this environment: `\newenvironment{inlineenum}[1][and]{\begin{enumerate*}[label={{\rm(\roman*)}}, itemjoin={{; }}, itemjoin*={{; #1 }},]}{\end{enumerate*}}` which adds semicolons between items and ends with "... foo; and (n.) bar", which I find more readable :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can load the [`enumitem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package with the option `inline`. It defines the environment `enumerate*` which does exactly what you want.

If you also want to change the default numbering from 1. to (1.) you can also do that within enumitem. The following MWE does what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    Note that
    \begin{enumerate*}[label=(\arabic*.)]
        \item  \label{1} this is an answer. 
        \item  By \ref{1}, we conclude that the answer works.
    \end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```